# HTML 5 File Attachment store in a WebSQL Database

Tags: html, local-storage

I am trying to build a web page (accessed by an Android Phone)  where the user can upload a photo from their Phone.

Then I want to store the image to a WebSQL database on the phone and send it back to the server via the xmlHTTP.send.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Do I somehow need to save the image to a Canvas tag and then use the URLtoData function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can reference to a local image in Android Browser. If you can, Canvas & toDataURL will work.